# Does a mathematical representation for orbital rotation between two concentric vortices exist?

Tags: geometry

An orbit circumscribes Vortex 1 and is inscribed by Vortex 2 such that the orbit exist as the interface between both vortices.  These vortices are pure spatial rotations in the same direction.  In mathematical literature, is there a relationship for the orbital rotation as a function of both vortices geometries, orbital size and orbital shape?  A new geometric structure may have been discovered, that is why I am asking this question.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Without additional detail I don't think many people will be able to help.

Comment: Please provide more detail. For example, what do you mean by a vortex? How did this arise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A geometric structure showing the relationship between orbital rotations or precession as a function of two spatial vortices, the orbital size and orbital shape was discovered and used to determine the motion of binary stars. The pure geometry of the structure is described by Equations 6 and 7 in the document below.

http://www.indjst.org/index.php/indjst/article/view/30008/25962

The vortices were used to synchronize a gravitational and electromagnetic field and produce a wave function which is not a mathematical tool but a real geometric structure. Both equations are transformed based on the placement of those fields within the geometric structure.